# Python: using same key for multiple dicts TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, types

Here's my code

```
sample_fh = dir + "sampleManifest.txt"
kids = {}
fid = {}
parents = {}
status = {}
sex = {}
with open(sample_fh) as f:
    for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            row = line.split('\t')
            fid = row[0]
            iid = row[1]
            relation  = row[5]
            status = row[6]
            sex = row[7]
            if relation != "Mother" and relation != "Father":
                    kids[iid] = 1
                    status[iid] = status
                    fid[iid] = fid
                    sex[iid]= row[7]
            if relation == "Mother" or relation == "Father":
                    parents[(fid,relation)]  = iid
```

I get this error:

```
status[iid] = status
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Not sure what's going on. Previous forums say this error is caused when your altering the string but I am pretty sure I am not altering any strings.

Comment: status is a str not a dict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fid = row[0]
iid = row[1]
relation = row[5]
status = row[6]
sex = row[7]
```

Here, you’re overwriting the dictionaries with the simple values you parsed from the lines in your file. As such, the dictionary is completely gone. For example, `status` is now a string, so when you later do `status[iid]`, you are using an indexed access to get a single character out of the string.

You should rename the variables there so you don’t overwrite your dictionaries:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    row = line.split('\t')
    row_fid = row[0]
    iid = row[1]
    relation  = row[5]
    row_status = row[6]
    row_sex = row[7]
    if relation != "Mother" and relation != "Father":
            kids[iid] = 1
            status[iid] = row_status
            fid[iid] = row_fid
            sex[iid]= row_sex
    if relation == "Mother" or relation == "Father":
            parents[(row_fid, row_relation)]  = iid
```

Comment: Thank you, its a bad habit from Perl. I would use %status and $status for the hash and value

Answer (score 6):

You reassign `status` in your code `status = row[6]` so it is no longer a dict, either use another name for your dict or change status in your loop just don't use it for both.

```
status = {} # starts as a dict
status = row[6] # now the name status points to something else i.e a str
```

Comment: Ooohhh Thank you. See this is a bad habit from being a Perl programmer. I'm used to declaring %status and $status in my scripts so I know which value to use. 

I feel so dumb now. Thanks!